# ROS Camera Calibration GStreamer Error

Tags: video, camera, gstreamer, launcher

I have a VM with ROS Noetic installed and I want to run a camera calibration on my USB Webcam. I followed the following guide and for the launcher, I put the following code:

```
<launch>
  <!-- This launchfile should bring up a node that broadcasts a ros image
       transport on /webcam/image_raw -->

  <arg name="DEVICEl" default="/dev/video0"/>
  <!-- The GStreamer framerate needs to be an integral fraction -->
  <arg name="FPS" default="30/1"/>
  <arg name="PUBLISH_FRAME" default="false"/>

  <node ns="left" name="gscam_driver_v4l" pkg="gscam" type="gscam" output="screen">
    <param name="camera_name" value="default"/>
    <param name="camera_info_url" value="package://gscam/examples/uncalibrated_parameters.ini"/>
    <param name="gscam_config" value="v4l2src device=$(arg DEVICEl) ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=$(arg FPS) ! ffmpegcolorspace"/>
    <param name="frame_id" value="/v4l_frame_l"/>
    <param name="sync_sink" value="true"/>
  </node>

  <node if="$(arg PUBLISH_FRAME)" name="v4l_transform" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="1 2 3 0 -3.141 0 /world /v4l_frame 10"/>
</launch>
```

I try to launch it and get the following response:

```
... logging to /home/dragonros/.ros/log/e62adeac-5d96-11eb-b879-09066182755f/roslaunch-ubuntu-42560.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

invalid ROS_HOSTNAME (an empty string)
invalid ROS_HOSTNAME (an empty string)
started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:35479/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /left/gscam_driver_v4l/camera_info_url: package://gscam/e...
 * /left/gscam_driver_v4l/camera_name: default
 * /left/gscam_driver_v4l/frame_id: /v4l_frame_l
 * /left/gscam_driver_v4l/gscam_config: v4l2src device=/d...
 * /left/gscam_driver_v4l/sync_sink: True
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.15.9

NODES
  /left/
    gscam_driver_v4l (gscam/gscam)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[left/gscam_driver_v4l-1]: started with pid [42574]
[ WARN] [1611445425.340701580]: invalid ROS_HOSTNAME (an empty string)
[ INFO] [1611445425.361034554]: Using gstreamer config from rosparam: "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=30/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace"
[ INFO] [1611445425.366515919]: camera calibration URL: package://gscam/examples/uncalibrated_parameters.ini
[ INFO] [1611445425.366725052]: Loaded camera calibration from package://gscam/examples/uncalibrated_parameters.ini

(gscam:42574): GStreamer-WARNING **: 15:43:45.455: 0.10-style raw video caps are being created. Should be video/x-raw,format=(string).. now.
[ INFO] [1611445425.455679084]: Time offset: 1611418553.717
[ INFO] [1611445425.555216304]: Publishing stream...
[ INFO] [1611445425.555412447]: Started stream.
[ERROR] [1611445425.555446013]: Could not get gstreamer sample.
[ INFO] [1611445425.555455586]: Stopping gstreamer pipeline...
[ INFO] [1611445425.557306732]: GStreamer stream stopped!
[ INFO] [1611445425.557374812]: Cleaning up stream and exiting...
[left/gscam_driver_v4l-1] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/dragonros/.ros/log/e62adeac-5d96-11eb-b879-09066182755f/left-gscam_driver_v4l-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

It says that it could not get gstreamer sample. Also, for some reason, when I plug my camera in to the computer, it creates both `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1`. This also what I get if I run `rosrun gscam gscam`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "invalid ROS_HOSTNAME" is connected with the environment variables.
Look at this page:

https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables

The assumption here is that your Cam is compatible with ROS.

Have you try this before calibration:

```
roscd gscam
cd bin
export GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=30/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace"
rosrun gscam gscam
```

Have you try camera_calibration package:

```
http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration
```

I am not sure if gscam is compatible with noetic.

```
https://index.ros.org/r/gscam/#noetic
```

Back then people have solved this by making sure gscam dependencies have met, and adding

"<param if="$(arg GST10)" name="gscam_config" value="v4l2src.....".

Have this looked:

```
https://github.com/ros-drivers/gscam/issues/25
https://github.com/ros-drivers/gscam/tree/master/examples
```

Also, consider closing :::https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865736/ros-camera-calibration

So we don't answer the same question twice.

I had indigo and I know how painful the compatibility issues are.

Good luck!